# Python linear programing solver for LARGE LPs

Tags: python, linear-programming

I am looking for a library in python capable of solving very large LPs (say 50,000 variables). I am currently using MATLAB linprog but I want to switch to python.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10705799/3166303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Commercial (might be free for academic usage)

Solver:

- [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/)

API:

- Gurobipy (shipped with Gurobi)

## Open-source

Solver:

- [clp](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp)
- [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/)

API:

- [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) -> calls GLPK, CLP/CBC, Gurobi, CPLEX / exports LP/MPS

#### Remark:

I would not call 50k vars a LARGE problem. At least the commercial products should handle these with ease!

Comment: Thank you sascha! Generally, how large should an LP be to be considered large? Could you name an application that needs, say 50 million, variables? Thanks again, I am in the learning phase :D

Comment: Sadly i can't give you an example, but i'm sure a lot of people are having models like this. This [SO-Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865178/limits-of-cplex) features a comment on CPLEX' limits in 2010, where 30 Millions variables are mentioned as upper bound. I think it is safe to assume, that this number got bigger since, especially because the estimated memory requirement is not that big! But as always: Size of a problem != Hardness of a problem.